# RESTful Webservice with PHP // Laravel or own setup

Tags: rest, laravel

i read a lot about frameworks like LARAVEL. I am currently trying to build my own RESTful web service. But doing that "by hand". I have absolutely no experience with these framework systems. It might be a general question, but I want to get your point of view on that.

What is a best practice to that. Is it "useless" building a web service from the ground up and it is common to use this framework? And what is the advantage. I do not want to start all over again and again by finding out that I should have started directly with these kind of frameworks to build the web service.

What are your opinions on that? Manually build everything? Or never do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel will save you a *lot* of time in the long run. A lot of tools are pre-built, and a lot of problems that you will run into are already solved. In my opinion it's well worth it to start with the framework. You will gain skills that will help you out on future projects.

Comment: Amazing Framework... thanks for the hint! It is so cool what ease it is to do things that cost a lot of time doing them by hand. Wow...